# Selenium and AssertTrue() connection

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Eclipse/Java and I have a Try/Catch like this:

```
            try {
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"));
        System.out.println("You Are Now Logged Out is present on the web page");
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("You Are Now Logged Out is NOT present on the web page");
        }
```

I guess I'm missing the Selenium connection with this forced failure (xxxOut) as how to get Selenium to report this as a failure? My TestNG reports my script ran OK without failures but if I look at the console I see "You Are Now Logged Out is NOT present on the web page", so I did have a failure (the expected text wasn't there).

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have caught the failure, the test has passed.  If you want to log your custom message and still report it as a failure, you should throw it again.  Add throw e after your sysout and the case would be reported as a failure.

If you do not want to log custom message, then do not catch it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the try/catch block necessary? If none of the methods under test are likely to throw exceptions it is preferable to keep the test simple

```
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"));
```

If the failure message doesn't need to be output to any particular output stream, but you want to retain custom messages

```
String failureMsg = "You Are Now Logged Out is NOT present on the web page";
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"), failureMsg);
String successMsg = "You Are Now Logged Out is present on the web page";
System.out.println(successMsg);
```

If logging is absolutely essential in your test

```
try {
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"));
    System.out.println("You Are Now Logged Out is present on the web page");
} catch (Throwable e) {
    String failureMsg = "You Are Now Logged Out is NOT present on the web page";
    fail(failureMsg, e)
    System.out.println(failureMsg);
}
```

As a matter of style I prefer the first option. Unless there is a very compelling reason to wrap the code in a Try/Catch I would advise against it because:

1. it isn't necessary based on the provided snippet; the assertTrue() call will throw an AssertionError which will fail the test cleanly and there is an overloaded version that allows for a custom message
2. catching all Throwable instances will catch the AssertionError instance and cause you to rethrow it (unnecessary), or call fail() (redundant, it just throws a new AssertionError)
3. rethrowing an exception other than AssertionError will cause the test to fail with an *Error* condition rather than a *Failure* condition, indicating that a test failed in a way that you didn't anticipate, which is generally considered a more serious error

Additionally it is generally not recommended to catch instances of Throwable.

Comment: If I remove the try/catch then the only thing I see in the TestNG report is an exception error line 143. So I guess I can look at the source code to see where the failure was but that isn't very friendly.

If I add the try/catch I can log a msg to the console and see exactly what the problem is. However, I'd like to save the console output to a file. I'm sure that is possible in Eclipse but i don't know how to do that?

Comment: The other odd thing about this is that this line works (it forces a failure and I get the null pointer exception pointing to line 143 in the console:
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"));

But this line passes and it should not:

    assertEquals("You Are Now Logged Out", driver.getPageSource().contains("You Are Now Logged xxxOut"));

I'm not sure why this line passes?